# Making ASP hyperlink enlarge on mouse over

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a ASP hyperlink in my aspx page. The link is just a text "Click here".

I have seen some effects in certain websites; if a user points his mouse on the link, then the link will zoom a bit larger in size. When the user moves the mouse pointer away from the link, the link returns back to its original size.

How do I achieve it? Is it done using CSS?

I have attached my existing CSS here.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {

        font-size: large;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CSS hover property

example ([more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp))

```
a:hover
{ 
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can also use javascript and the mouseover property of the a tag

Answer (score 2):

you can acheive this using css selectors http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes targeting the hover pseudo class to apply a new style when the mouse hovers over the link

```
<a href="www.google.com">go to google</a>

<style>
    a { font-family: Arial; }
    a:hover { font-size: large; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.style1
{
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.style1:hover
{
    font-size:larger;
}
```

Comment: thanks..dis was exactly what i wanted :) will mark urs as best ans :)

Comment: @user851777, my answer was made to match your example; of course there is a:hover but I wanted to give you the solution based on your specific CSS.